# What is the purpose of the resistor in this circuit

Tags: circuits

I am trying to convert an AC input into DC output using Diodes, and I found the following diagram for the circuit:

[image: The circuit in question]

I understand the diagram, but I don't fully get why the resistor has to be there, assuming that the V_out would be connected to the rest of the system.

Comment: It doesn't need to be there. It's probably just a dummy load here so there's current on the output of the rectifier so you can measure the output voltage.

Comment: should probably consider a capacitor that can handle the voltage if you need something closer to DC.  Just be sure to take proper safety precautions since a capacitor does store energy!

Answer (score 2):

Power supply schematics like this one often contain an arbitrary *load resistance* just to specify where the output of the circuit is taken off. It is not part of the power supply circuit itself.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a part of a bleeder resistor idea for the later part of the circuit.

If there is a capacitor somewhere, it may remain charged for a long time after the circuit is switched off. This may harm a person who opens the circuit or touches the output, expecting there to be no power because circuit is switched off. To make sure this person is safe, a large resistor is added, calculated in a way to discharge the capacitance in a minute or so. Somewhere around 1 MOhm.

If resistance is about 50 Ohm, then it is likely the author put it there as an example of a load, 'connect your load here, like this'.

In any case, this resistor is not strictly needed for this circuit to operate.